# How do I execute a script with Cloudinit, using the nocloud data source

Tags: cloud-init, rhel8

I am trying to automate provisioning of linux machines (rhel8) using cloudinit.

For this purpose I created an ISO with the following content:

```
[root@]# tree rhel82test1/
rhel82test1/
├── meta-data
├── network-config
├── scripts
│   └── per-instance
│       └── demo.sh
└── user-data

2 directories, 4 files
```

This iso gets added to the VM during virt-install.

The user-data, meta-data and network-config get applied as expected. However I expected the demo.sh script to be executed as well. I see in the logs that config-scripts-per-instance gets run, but the script is not executed. It is als not present in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts

What am I doing wrong here. Is this not the correct way to have scripts executed?

Answer (score 0):

See [source](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/master/cloudinit/sources/DataSourceNoCloud.py), not implemented for NoCloud